# Изменить содержание поста wordpress перед сохранением в БД

Tags: php, wordpress, php7

Сейчас очень "модно" писать без пробелов (хз почему 70% пользователей не ставят пробелы после знаков препинаний) пытаюсь решить эту проблему через фильтр wp_insert_post_data.
Получилась такая функция, но почему то не работает

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'my_pre_save_post', 0 );
function my_pre_save_post ( $data ){
    if ($data['post_date'] == $data['post_modified']) // Если пост новый
        $data['post_content'] = str_replace('/([^\s]?)\s?([.,?!:;])\s?([^\s]?)/u', "\$1\$2 \$3", $data['post_content'] );
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий:

```
preg_replace("/([^\s]?)\s?([.,?!:;])\s?([^\s]?)/u", "\$1\$2 \$3" , $data);
```

Источник: https://www.cyberforum.ru/php-beginners/thread1435322.html

Comment: Спасибо, точно preg_replace, а не str_replace